# помогите оптимизировать LINQ запрос

Tags: sql-server, linq, ado.net

в моём dataset имеется 2 таблички: customers,orders соединенные по столбцу 'CustomerNo':

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Передо мной стоит задача, вывести статистику продаж по городам. Вот мой код:

```
var query = from c in customers.AsEnumerable()
                    let countSale = orders.Count(o => o.CustomerNo == c.CustomerNo)
                    select new
                    {
                        c.City,
                        countSale
                    };
        dataGridView1.DataSource = query.ToList();
```

Вот мой вывод:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне не нравится такой вывод, как можно сделать подзапрос в LINQ,
чтобы вывести город, и сумму продаж по нему (по моей переменной countSale)?
Проще говоря в конечном итоге хочу увидеть что то вроде:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вы поймите для начала, какой запрос вам нужно составить на уровне sql (`SELECT city, count(orderId) FROM orders AS o INNER JOIN customers AS c ON (c.CustomerNo = o.CustomerNo) GROUP BY city` ) а потом попробуйте именно его реализовать в помощью LINQ

Comment: @teran, ваш запрос возвращает то, что нужно

Comment: тогда поясните что надо возвращать, ибо приведенный запрос должен возвращать количество заказов сгруппированных по городам.

Comment: @teran, ну по сути, это и есть статистика продаж по городам :)

Comment: а, пардоньте, прочитал "НЕ то что нужно"

Comment: вот запрос возвращающий количество продаж по городам

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT CAST.CITY,
                COUNT(ORD.ORDERID) OVER (PARTITION BY CAST.CITY) AS COUNT_ORDERS
  FROM CUSTOMERS CAST
    LEFT JOIN ORDERS ORD
      ON ORD.EMPLOYEESID = CAST.CUSTOMERSID;

Comment: можно здесь посмотреть как на шарпиках такой трюк сделать:
https://stackoverflow.com/q/9980568/10384085

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var query = from c in customers
         join o in orders on c.CustomerNo equals o.CustomerNo
         group o by c into g
         select new  { City=g.Key.City,
                       Countsale = g.Count(o=>o.CustomerNo==g.Key.CustomerNo)
                     };
         dataGridView1.DataSource = query.ToList();
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]